# Pythonでconcatで連番のデータフレームを縦結合

Tags: python, pandas

pandasでデータフレームdf1からdf25までを縦結合したいと考えています。
ぐぐると2つの結合のものばかりで、3つ以上もOKとは書いていますが

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,...,df25])
```

のような書き方は避けたいと考えています。
他言語だとdf1-df25のように連番を処理するテクニックがあったりするのですが、pythonでもうまくかけるものなのでしょうか。

現在の案としては`def`でdf2にdf1とdf2を結合したものを代入、それとdf3を結合したものをdf3に代入というのをループで回そうか、位しか思いつかないです。

文字列の処理でうまくかけないか考えております。
アイデアを貸してくださる方、よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
dfというリストの中にdf[1]からdf[25]というデータフレームを格納するところまではできたのですが、concatの際はどのように書けばよいのでしょうか。pd.concat(df)やpd.concat([df])ではうまくいきませんでした。

→`pd.concat(df)`で無事解決しました。勘違いでした。すいません。

Comment: 単に df1～df25を生成する段階からlistまたはdictで管理しておけば良いかと思うのですが、それでは駄目なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あまり褒められたやり方ではないですが、こういう方法もあります。

```
pd.concat([globals()[x] for x in globals() if x.startswith("df")])
```

Comment: magichan さんもコメントされていますが、本来はdfを作成する時点でリストに追加するようにし、pd.concat(dfが入ったリスト)とするのがあるべき姿かと。